# Use IdentityServer with ASP Core and Web API

Tags: asp.net, api

I'm working on converting a monolithic web application to a ASP Core client with a (ASP Core) Web Api. Right now the application uses a Microsoft login.

We're investigating using IdentityServer to take care of the authentication middleware, but I'm having trouble understanding the exact role and place of IdentityServer.

Is IdentityServer a separate web application that need to be hosted? or is it part of the Web Api, or the client ASP Core app that will consume the Api?

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: "Is IdentityServer a separate web application that need to be hosted?" - [Yes](https://identityserver.io/)

Comment: Thanks! I had indeed found the site and the documentation, but to me it never became clear if it's supposed to be part of your application, or a seperate system altogether.